# Calculate bottom left corner of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about calculating the bottom left corner of a div x and y coordinates using JavaScript or jQuery.

How would you find the bottom left corner of the green box, for example?
HTML:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="result">Click an element.</div>
<p>
  This is the best way to <span>find</span> an offset.
</p>
<div class="abs">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  p {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  div.abs {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 220px;
    top: 35px;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

JavaScript:

```
$( "*", document.body ).click(function( event ) {
  var offset = $( this ).offset();
  event.stopPropagation();
  $( "#result" ).text( this.tagName +
    " coords ( " + offset.left + ", " + offset.top + " )" );
});
```

Link to JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/hfjVQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom left coordinate will be the offset top position, plus the height of the element. You can use the following:

```
$(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight(true);
```

We use [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) with the `true` parameter, since it will calculate the actual outer height of the element including the border and any margins that might be applied.

So your code will look like this:

```
$("*", document.body).on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var offset = $( this ).offset();

    $( "#result" ).text(this.tagName+" coords ("+offset.left+", "+offset.top+", "+(offset.top + $(this).outerHeight(true))+")");
});
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/hfjVQ/1/)

Comment: Oops, didn't that only calculate the Y axis of the bottom left point?